# Scrolling to b-collapse element with <a> tag

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have an SVG element that collapes an b-collapse element when i click on it. Now i want the browser to automatically scroll down to the element that just showed up. It works with a simple  tag pointing to the id of my b-collapse around the SVG element, but the problem is that the browser doesnt scroll far enough, because the b-collapse element isn't fully shown when the scrolling is triggered. Is there an easy way around this?

Here is (some) of my code:

```
<a v-for="(item, index)  in items" :key="index"
    v-b-toggle="'collapse-'+index"
    v-bind:href="'#collapse-'+index">
  <rect
              v-bind:y="y(item.box[1])"
              v-bind:x="x(item.box[0])"
              v-bind:width="(width (item.box[2], item.box[0]))"
              v-bind:height="(height(item.box[3], item.box[1]))"
              style="stroke:#00aeef;stroke-width:2;stroke-opacity:0.9;"
              rx="5" ry="5"
  ><title>{{item.category}}</title></rect></a>

<b-collapse :id="'collapse-'+index" class="mt-2">...</b-collapse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with a function and a timeout using Javascript:

```
jumpto (index) {
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById(index).scrollIntoView()
  }, 200)
```